# Iterating through a dictionary using dates

Tags: python, date, python-2.7, iteration

Can any one help me how to iterate through dictionary with dates, I have the data set like this

```
data=[{u'a': u'D', u'b': 100.0, u'c': 201L, u'd': datetime.datetime(2007, 12, 29, 0, 0), u'e': datetime.datetime(2008, 1, 1, 6, 27, 41)},
      {u'a': u'W', u'b': 100.0, u'c': 201L, u'd': datetime.datetime(2007, 12, 29, 0, 0), u'e': datetime.datetime(2008, 2, 4, 6, 27, 41)},
      {u'a': u'W', u'b': 100.0, u'c': 202L, u'd': datetime.datetime(2007, 12, 30, 0, 0), u'e': datetime.datetime(2008, 1, 1, 4, 20, 44)},
      {u'a': u'D', u'b': 100.0, u'c': 202L, u'd': datetime.datetime(2007, 12, 30, 0, 0), u'e': datetime.datetime(2008, 3, 11, 6, 27, 41)},
      {u'a': u'D', u'b': 100.0, u'c': 202L, u'd': datetime.datetime(2007, 12, 30, 0, 0), u'e': datetime.datetime(2008, 5, 8, 11, 2, 41)},
      {u'a': u'D', u'b': 100.0, u'c': 203L, u'd': datetime.datetime(2008, 1, 2, 0, 0), u'e': datetime.datetime(2008, 6, 1, 6, 27, 41)},
      {u'a': u'W', u'b': 100.0, u'c': 204L, u'd': datetime.datetime(2008, 2, 9, 0, 0), u'e': datetime.datetime(2008, 4, 21, 12, 30, 51)},
      {u'a': u'D', u'b': 100.0, u'c': 204L, u'd': datetime.datetime(2008, 2, 9, 0, 0), u'e': datetime.datetime(2008, 8, 15, 15, 45, 10)}]
```

How can i bring it into the dictionary of below format

```
res={u'201L':(1,0,1),(2,1,0),(3,0,0),(4,0,0).. so on till (12,0,0),
u'202L':(1,1,0),(2,0,0),(3,0,1),(4,0,0),(5,0,1)...(12,0,0),
u'203L':(1,0,0),(2,0,0),(3,0,0),(4,0,0),(5,1,0)...(12,0,0),
u'204L':(1,0,0),(2,0,0),(3,0,0),(4,1,0),(5,0,0),(6,0,0,(7,0,0),(8,0,1)...(12,0,0)}
```

where 1, 2, 3 is the first, second month and so on from their card issue date i.e
for `201L` issue date is `datetime.datetime(2007, 12, 29, 0, 0)`, `202L` it is    `datetime.datetime(2007, 12, 30, 0, 0)`

first month means from `2007-12-29` to `2008-1-29`

```
  (1,0,1)---where 1 is the first month
  0 is no of times W
  1 is no of times D
```

I tried something like this

```
data_dict=defaultdict(Counter)
date_dic={}
for x in data:
  a,b,c,d=x['a'],x['c'],x['d'],x['e']
  data_dict[b][a] += 1
for key , value in data_dict.items():
   date_dic[key] = tuple(map(datetime.date.isoformat, (c,d)))
   for value in range(1,30):
      if value not x: continue
```

I have been stuck after if loop what can i add to get in the above format.I end up  getting something like this as my output,

```
defaultdict(<class 'collections.Counter'>, {201L: Counter({u'D': 1, u'W': 1}), 202L: Counter({u'D': 2, u'W': 1}), 203L: Counter({u'D': 1}), 204L: Counter({u'D': 1, u'W': 1})})
```

Comment: I see that user `204L` has *2* card issuing dates; perhaps you need to recalculate the buckets per *transaction* in that case? Currently my answer assumes just *one* starting date per user, we could switch that to caching the buckets per issuing date instead.

Comment: So for `204L`, the withdrawal is in the 3rd 30-day period, but the deposit is in the *6th* bucket compared to the new issue date, vs. the 7th bucket my current code puts it in. Can you confirm?

Comment: We can expand the buckets as needed, I'll update.

Comment: You can iterate over `v` too; that is just a regular Python list.

Comment: Right, that's because my answer creates buckets dynamically; if there was no activity beyond the first month there is no second bucket. Use `try`, `except IndexError` to handle those and set the count  to 0 for that user for that month.

Comment: It is a dictionary; I meant you need to assume a default; whatever your code needs to do its job. If you are plotting second-month withdrawals then default to 0 when you get an index error, etc.

Comment: That looks overly complicated; looks like it is time for you to post a new question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd create a list of dates, then find the 'bucket' to put each item into from that list.

You can create new dates relative from a starting point using [`datetime.timedelta()` objects](http://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#datetime.timedelta):

```
startdate = data[0]['d']
buckets = [startdate + datetime.timedelta(days=30) * i for i in xrange(12)]
```

Now you have 12 dates to compare everything else against, so you know what bucket to put each subsequent value in:

```
>>> buckets
[datetime.datetime(2007, 12, 29, 0, 0), datetime.datetime(2008, 1, 28, 0, 0), datetime.datetime(2008, 2, 27, 0, 0), datetime.datetime(2008, 3, 28, 0, 0), datetime.datetime(2008, 4, 27, 0, 0), datetime.datetime(2008, 5, 27, 0, 0), datetime.datetime(2008, 6, 26, 0, 0), datetime.datetime(2008, 7, 26, 0, 0), datetime.datetime(2008, 8, 25, 0, 0), datetime.datetime(2008, 9, 24, 0, 0), datetime.datetime(2008, 10, 24, 0, 0), datetime.datetime(2008, 11, 23, 0, 0)]
```

We can then use the [`bisect` module](http://docs.python.org/2/library/bisect.html) to find the matching bucket:

```
from bisect import bisect

bisect(buckets, somedate) - 1  # Returns a value from 0 - 11
```

We create such buckets *per user* so we need to keep track of the buckets in a separate mapping. We'll actually create buckets on the fly as needed to fit the current transaction date.

Next, we use a [`collections.defaultdict` instance](http://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict) to track per-key tallies (key `c` in your input):

```
from collections import defaultdict

res = defaultdict(list)
empty_counts = {'D': 0, 'W': 0}
```

This creates a list for your buckets to hold, and a empty counts dictionary for the deposits and withdrawals. I used a dictionary here because that is *much* easier to work with than having to manipulate (immutable) tuples later on. I also did not include the month number (1 - 12); no point, you already have an index for each bucket (0 - 11), and you can have a variable number of buckets.

We need to create buckets and counters as needed to fit the current date in; instead of scanning throuh the data to find the max transaction date per user we just expand our buckets and counts list as needed:

```
def expand_buckets(buckets, bucket_counts, start, transaction):
    # This function modifies the buckets and bucket_counts lists in-place
    if not buckets:
        # initialize the lists
        buckets.append(start)
        bucket_counts.append(dict(empty_counts))

    # keep adding 30-day spans until we can fit the transaction date
    while buckets[-1] + datetime.timedelta(days=30) < transaction:
        buckets.append(buckets[-1] + datetime.timedelta(days=30))
        bucket_counts.append(dict(empty_counts))
```

**Now** we can start counting:

```
per_user_buckets = defaultdict(list)

for entry in data:
    user = entry['c']
    type = entry['a']
    transaction_date = entry['e']
    buckets = per_user_buckets[user]
    bucket_counts = res[user]
    expand_buckets(buckets, bucket_counts, entry['d'], transaction_date)

    # count transaction date entries per bucket
    bucket = bisect(buckets, transaction_date) - 1
    bucket_counts[bucket][type] += 1
```

The `bisect` call makes picking the right bucket easy and fast.

The result for your example input is:

```
>>> pprint(dict(res))
{201L: [{'D': 1, 'W': 0},
        {'D': 0, 'W': 1}],
 202L: [{'D': 0, 'W': 1},
        {'D': 0, 'W': 0},
        {'D': 1, 'W': 0},
        {'D': 0, 'W': 0},
        {'D': 1, 'W': 0}],
 203L: [{'D': 0, 'W': 0},
        {'D': 0, 'W': 0},
        {'D': 0, 'W': 0},
        {'D': 0, 'W': 0},
        {'D': 0, 'W': 0},
        {'D': 1, 'W': 0}],
 204L: [{'D': 0, 'W': 0},
        {'D': 0, 'W': 0},
        {'D': 0, 'W': 1},
        {'D': 0, 'W': 0},
        {'D': 0, 'W': 0},
        {'D': 0, 'W': 0},
        {'D': 1, 'W': 0}]}
```

Comment: `per_user_buckets = defaultdict(lambda: user_buckets(entry['d']))` might work as well.

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian: That presumes `entry` is in the local scope at that time then; I'd prefer the explicit handling here.